# Make link using the target at point and ignore the ID or CUSTOM_ID

Tags: org-mode, org-link

Following situation:

```
* Headline
:PROPERTIES:
:CUSTOM_ID: ignore_it
:END:
...
...
long text
...
...
<<this is the target>> ...
.....
some other long text
```

With `org-store-link` (`C-c l`) I get a link to the headline and not to the target in `<<..>>`. This is annoying if I have a long text between the CUSTOM_ID and the real target.

Any idea to solve this?

---

EDIT: According the [documentation](https://orgmode.org/manual/Handling-Links.html) I shouldn't have the problem:

"For Org files, if there is a '<< target>>' at point, the link points to the target. Otherwise it points to the current headline, which is also the description."

I have the latest version. 9.4.

Comment: Where is your cursor when you press `C-c l`? If you place it in the link and then press `C-c l` there  should be no problem.

Comment: @NickD Unfortunately, it doesn't work. I've also tested it with a clean init.el (`emacs -Q`). Emacs uses the headline name (i.e. "file.org::*Headline")  or the CUSTOM_ID or the global ID.

Comment: There does seem some funkiness going on. I would report it as a bug with `M-x org-submit-bug-report`.When I try it, I get *two* links stored in `org-stored-links`, so when I use `C-c C-l` to insert a link, I can go `<Up>` twice in the history: that seems to be the correct link. The first one is the CUSTOM_ID one. Do you get the same thing?

Comment: @NickD "funkiness" describes it well.  I get the same thing, but not always. Sometimes it's correct. And sometimes if I use 'C-c C-l' a second time, I get the correct link.